# How can I run the browser in the background with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, browser, server

I am making a SERVER-CLIENT in python, the problem is that I cannot get the client-side browser to run in the background, the problem is to send the link to the client, and have it open it automatically in the background with your default browser.

PD: How could I list the number of clients connected to the server in real time?

SERVER

```
from socket import socket


server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 8888)


client_socket = socket()
client_socket.connect(server_address)
estado = True


while estado:



    enlace = input(
        "Por favor, ingresa el enlace que deseas abrir (o 'exit' para salir): ")


    if enlace == 'exit':

        client_socket.send(enlace.encode())

        client_socket.close()
        estado = False

    else:

        client_socket.send(enlace.encode())


        respuesta = client_socket.recv(4096)


        print(respuesta.decode())
```

CLIENT

```
from socket import socket
from subprocess import getoutput
import webbrowser
from time import sleep


server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 8888)


server_socket = socket()


server_socket.bind(server_address)


server_socket.listen(1)


client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

estado = True

while estado:

    enlace = client_socket.recv(4096).decode()

    webbrowser.open_new(enlace)


    if enlace == 'exit':

        client_socket.close()

        server_socket.close()
        estado = False

    else:

        salida = getoutput(enlace)

        client_socket.send(enlace.encode())

    sleep(0.1)
```